# Vectorized pandas pd.Timestamp operation

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a column of a pandas dataframe stored as integer (yyyymmddHHMM format) into a Timestamp. This column is actually a pandas dataframe index. Consider the following MWE:

```
def get_digits(vector,first_digit,last_digit):
    return (vector // 10**last_digit) % 10**(first_digit-last_digit)

data = {'timestamp':[201911200830,201807131820],'value':[1,2]}
df_t=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The operations to obtain the Year and the Month for instance:

```
df_t.timestamp.values // 10**10
get_digits(df_t.timestamp.values,10,8)
```

Yield `array([2019, 2018])` and `array([11, 7])`.

Strangely, `pd.Timestamp` does not seem to support arrays as inputs since the operation only works for a single input as below:

```
pd.Timestamp(df_t.timestamp.values[0] // 10**8, get_digits(df_t.timestamp.values[0],8,6), get_digits(df_t.timestamp.values[0],6,4), get_digits(df_t.timestamp.values[0],4,2), get_digits(df_t.timestamp.values[0],2,0))
```

Results in `Timestamp('2019-11-20 08:30:00')` as I would expect. But if I drop the `[0]` index it gives me the following error in the MWE:

> TypeError: Cannot convert input [[2019 2018]] of type class 'numpy.ndarray' to Timestamp

Any ideas on how to contour this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with specify format of data - `%Y%m%d%H%M` means `YYYYMMDDHHMM`:

```
df_t['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df_t['timestamp'], format='%Y%m%d%H%M')
print (df_t)
            timestamp  value
0 2019-11-20 08:30:00      1
1 2018-07-13 18:20:00      2
```

Answer (score 0):

> **EDIT** This is not a vectorized approach

You can use [pd.Series.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) to invoke function on values of a column

```
df_t.timestamp.apply(lambda ts: pd.Timestamp(ts // 10**8, get_digits(ts,8,6), get_digits(ts,6,4), get_digits(ts,4,2), get_digits(ts,2,0)))

0   2019-11-20 08:30:00
1   2018-07-13 18:20:00
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: If use `.apply` there are loops under the hoos, so not vectorized.

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for pointing it out. I wasn't aware of vectorized functions.